# vb6 project in server with mdb location in E drive

Tags: ms-access, server, vb6

i have a software made in vb6 and mdb database with crystal report, is there is any option to work the software in server(local/other). the database location is E drive only

Comment: If your VB6 application is running only at your (Windows) server it could be available to users over local network or internet by RemoteApp.
https://newhelptech.wordpress.com/2017/07/23/step-by-step-how-to-deploy-remote-desktop-services-in-windows-server-2016/

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what "in server(local/other)" means?

Comment: ie the database works only in E drive, if we share the exe through local server the database location is change so we cannot be accessible, can u put the .exe file and db file in cloud, but here also the problem is db location..